# A folder is mysteriously added into my .gitignore file

Tags: eclipse, gitignore, tex

I have an Eclipse project which contains only a single folder "MyFolder" containing a LaTeX file "myfile.tex". For some reason, whenever I refresh the project or save a file, the following line is added to the .gitignore file at the root of my project:

```
/MyFolder
```

I.e., someone mysteriously tells GIT to ignore the entire folder which contains my tex file. I suspect it's the tex plugin doing this. But why? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to:

*Team* → *Git* → *Projects* and unmark:

> "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore".